# Azure App Config adding JSON through Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-app-configuration

I've created an Azure App Config and am calling the following to add a key / value pair through an Azure Cloud Shell:

```
az appconfig kv set -n $appConfigName --content-type application/json --key "tenantXYZ:1" --value {\"FilterConfig\":{\"ClientId\":\"GHRYWQAXCFGH\",\"Url\":\"http://localhost:9091\"}}
```

but i get the following error

[image: parse error]

what's the correct syntax for adding a JSON object called FilterConfig with ClientId and Url properties ? I'm able to add this type ok via the Portal but need to be able to do it on the command line also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@auburg, you should put the whole value in quotes

```
az appconfig kv set -n $appConfigName --content-type application/json --key "tenantXYZ:1" --value "{\"FilterConfig\":{\"ClientId\":\"GHRYWQAXCFGH\",\"Url\":\"http://localhost:9091\"}}"
```

Comment: Yes that and i needed to add additional quotes - this is what i ended up with: "{\""FilterConfig\"":{\""ClientId\"":\""GHRYWQAXCFGH\"",\""Url\"":\""http://localhost:9091\""}}"